# How do I prove that a function preserving Cauchy sequences is uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, cauchy-sequences, uniform-continuity

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded interval. Assume a function $f:A \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfies that for every cauchy sequence ${x_n}$ where $x_n \in  A$ the sequence ${f(x_n)}$ is also a cauchy sequence. How can I prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous in $A$?

I have tried extending $A$ to be a closed interval $A'=[a,b]$ where $a=\inf A  ,b=\sup A$, and proving that for every convergent series $x_n \in A'$ the series $f(x_n)$ also converges. This would allow me to use the series definition of continuity and thus because this is a closed interval it would also be uniformly continuous. But because the function is not necessarily defined at $f(a)$ I haven't been able to do that.

Comment: But you can extend $f$ continuously on the limit points.

Comment: @Berci but how  do I show that when x_n is a series that converges to the endpoints, then the limit of f(x_n) is the same for every x_n?

Comment: If two sequences led to different limits, the interspersed sequence would not be sent to a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: I don't think the statement you want to prove is correct. I think a counterexample is $f(x) = 0$ for $x\leq 0$ and $f(x) = 1$ for $x>0$. Did you mean that $f(x_n)$ must converge to $f(\lim x_n)$?

Comment: Why is that a counterexample? If you take x_n=(-1)/n then this is a cauchy sequence but f(x_n) is not

Answer (score 1):

$A=(a,b)$. Let $(x_n)$ be any sequence in $A$ converging to $b$, for example $x_n := b-(b-a)/n$. Then $(x_n)$ is Cauchy. By our hypothesis $f(x_n)$ is Cauchy, hence converging to say $\kappa$ as $\mathbb{R}$ is complete. Similarly, we can find that for any sequence in $A$ that converges to $a$ converges to say $\lambda$ when $f$ is applied. Extend $f$ to $\tilde{f}$ as $\tilde{f}(x)=f(x)$ when $x \in A$, $\tilde{f}(b)=\kappa$ and $\tilde{f}(a)=\lambda$. Continuity of $\tilde{f}$ follows from our construction and the rest follows from your argument.

I hope this helps.